# OpenLayers tooltips

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping

Please point me to examples of combining OpenLayers and any external tooltip libraries like [this](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html). I try to use native OpenLayers tools for building tooltips [here](http://nextgis.ru/demo/korus/korus.html), but they not flexible and customizable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the *best* way to do it, but it's [one way](http://krefft.org/test/ol/tooltips.html). You can improve on it.

[image]

[**DEMO LINK**](http://krefft.org/test/ol/tooltips.html)

The key here is to move the wrapper/trigger around onFeatureHighlighted event.

```
var handler_featurehighlighted = function (e) {

    var tt_trigger = tooltipApi.getTrigger();
    tt_trigger.css({ 'left': mouseEvent.clientX + 'px', 'top': mouseEvent.clientY + 'px' });

    $(".tooltip").html("<strong>Feature Name: " + e.feature.attributes.name + "</strong>");

    tooltipApi.show();

};
var handler_featureunhighlighted = function (e) {
    tooltipApi.hide();
};
var highlightControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(myToolTipLayer, {
    hover: true,
    highlightOnly: true,
    renderIntent: "temporary",
    eventListeners: {
        featurehighlighted: handler_featurehighlighted,
        featureunhighlighted: handler_featureunhighlighted
    }
});

map.addControl(highlightControl);

highlightControl.activate();
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenGeo has a workshop on Introduction to Openlayes in which a section about Integration with Other Frameworks was introduced [here](http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/integration/jqui-dialog.html)